# How could I create an array on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
    $("#years").ionRangeSlider({
      type: "double",
      grid: true,
      min: 0,
      from: 10,
      to: 11,
      max: 2018,
      prettify_enabled:false,
      values: [
          "1910", "1920", "1930",
          "1940", "1950", "1960",
          "1970", "1980", "1990",
          "2000", "2010", "2018"
      ]
    });
```

I need to be able to generate `from 0 to 2018` on this part

```
      values: [
          "1910", "1920", "1930",
          "1940", "1950", "1960",
          "1970", "1980", "1990",
          "2000", "2010", "2018"
      ]
```

But I can't go manually as they're 2 thousands values. So I thought of using a loop, something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2018; i++;) {

}
```

However, I am not sure how would I generate the object

```
      [
          "0", .... , "2018"
      ]
```

Comment: `Array(2019).fill().map((_, i) => i)`

Comment: can you create jsfiddle example of what you have done.

Comment: @Dkouk what I have done is in the question, I have provided the idea of using the for but I am asking how would I fill it, if i'd knew how to do it, I wouldn't have asked...

Comment: doesn't `.fill` still leave the array holey? i'd advice this: `[...Array(2919)].map((_, i) => i)`

Comment: var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 2018; i++;) {
  values.push(i);
}

Comment: And so you don't have to fix this every Jan 1, you could replace the `2019` in any answer with `(new Date()).getFullYear() + 1`

Comment: @GottZ yup, we've got an answer with that which I am accepting in a minute, thanks tho

Comment: @msanford actually that is really helpful, would you mind placing the bit of code to do that into an answer for future users?

Comment: @rob.m you don't seems to realize what i mean. there is a difference between an array that has or had holes in between (wich using plain `Array(n)` creates) and a properly filled array. i'm talking javascript engine side of stuff here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an array with 2019 slots (for 0 to 2018 inclusive) and fill then map to its index:

```
Array(2019).fill().map((_, i) => i)
```

And if you want a string you can coerce via concatenation or interpolation:

```
Array(2019).fill().map((_, i) => `${i}`)
```

Comment: great, thanks. Works, will accept as soon as it let me

Comment: you mean `values: Array(2019).fill().map((_, i) => i)`

Comment: Yeah, but not understood immediately until later (OP said "how to change the values" or similar)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from({length: currentYear + 1}, (_,i) => i)
```

Comment: oh nice, didn't know .from, will check it out

Answer (score 2):

To adapt Li357's (or any) answer so you don't have to change this code every new year's:

```
Array((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1).fill().map((_, i) => i)
```

And in this case, probably also set your ionRangeSlider's `max:` value to this as well.

So set a variable somewhere and use it, because creating `new Date()` can be a bit heavy.

Comment: this is nice, very nice indeed! Thanks

Comment: you mean to Array((new Date()).getFullYear() ?

Comment: @rob.m, no, `getFullYear()` will return 2018, but you need `years +1` slots because your array's first value is 0, same as the other answers.

Comment: Oh I simply adapted @Li357 's answer for this as a note on maintainability. I appreciate the gesture but you could accept that one :)

Comment: yes you're right, I was a bit undecided to what to accept, because actually @Li357 correctly answered and as the first one too, yet I thought of future users and to provide a better answer I thought this one had to be accept. Anyway, accepted that one but thank you once again

Comment: That's kind of you. Thanks! Strictly speaking the rule is "accept whichever you want for whatever reason you find most helpful" but I didn't want to poach an obviously more generic answer to "how to fill an array".